# How to properly read and parse data from Firebase in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I have a database in Firebase which currently I can access through CURL like this

`curl "https://mydb.firebaseio.com/my_data.json?auth=XKJYED78634jsvdffwu7riugwer"`

I want to make a Nim script to actively listen to this data for any changes and then generate web pages accordingly, what would be the best way to do that ? I am not able to find any library for Firebase support in Nim.

---

Thanks @jason, based on your response, this is what I did:

```
import std/[httpclient, json] 
const url = "https://mydb.firebaseio.com/my_data.json?auth=XKJYED78634jsvdffwu7riugwer"
var client = newHttpClient() 
let parsedJsonObj = parseJson(client.getContent(url)) 
client.close() 
echo parsedJsonObj
```

Then I compiled this with -d:ssl flag and this is successfully reading the JSON data and dumping it to stdout. Another problem I am facing is that this JSON data is unstructured, is there any way to iterate through all records without knowing the key names ?

Comment: Nim can deal with json using its `JsonNode` object-variant type. It should be possible to check JsonNode-stuff for equality and printing it out. So your task is possible. However, where you'll be facing issues is if you want to actually extract a value and do anything with it outside of the JsonNode type, when you know neither the key-name nor the value-type at compile-time. Not knowing that type means not being able to assign it to variables, basically. You'll have to send the JsonNode-object everywhere and every time deal with all possible types it could have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in webdev, but given that's a link that returns a `json` formatted file you can do something like the following:

```
import std/[httpclient, htmlgen, asyncdispatch, json]
const url = "https://mydb.firebaseio.com/my_data.json?auth=XKJYED78634jsvdffwu7riugwer" # do this safer using dotenvs or similar

proc buildSite(): Future[string] {.async.} =
  let
    myHttpClient = newAsyncHttpClient()
    data = parseJson(await(myHttpClient.getContent(url)))
  # Do stuff with `data, we'll just make a header for an example
  result = h1("Hellow World")
  myHttpClient.close()
  

proc main() {.async.} =
  var isWatchingSite = true
  while isWatchingSite:
    try:
      let site = await buildSite()
    except HttpRequestError as err:
      echo err.msg
    
    await sleepAsync(10000)
  
waitFor main()
```

Comment: Comment was showing weird code formatting which wasn't readable so updated the original post with the response and deleted the comment

Comment: In `std/json` there are `pairs` and `mpairs` iterators that can be used which will iterate the `JsonNode` you then can check the `.kind` and do operations based off that.